# Proving that the bias of the derivative of Parzen-Rosenblatt (kernel density) estimator is of order $O(h^2) $ and $O(h)$ when $h$ approaches $0$

Tags: self-study, estimation, nonparametric, bias, kernel-smoothing

I came across this property that I don't get and I couldn't find the proof anywhere:

Suppose we have a density $K$ of the standard normal distribution and $K'$ its derivative. Suppose that the density $f$ is of class $C^4$ in $\Bbb{R}$ .

Let $\hat{f'}_{h,n} = \cfrac{1}{nh^2}\sum_{j=1}^n K'(\cfrac{x-X_j}{h})$ be the estimator of the density $f'$ with $h > 0 $.

For a small $h$, as in if $h$ approaches $0$ the bias verifies :

$B(\hat{f'}_{h,n}) = O(h)$ and $B(\hat{f'}_{h,n}) = O(h^2)$.

***Can someone explain to me how did we get to that result?***

**EDIT**: I found this theorem:

[image]

But here we are discussing the density $f$ and not $f'$. ***How can we extend the proposition?***

**EDIT**: Here is my attempt :

$$E(\hat{f'}_{h,n}(x)) = \int\cfrac{1}{h^2}K'(\cfrac{u-x}{h})f'(u)$$

Let $u = x +hv$ so we get :
$$ E(\hat{f'}_{h,n}(x)) = \cfrac{1}{h}\int f'(hv+x) K'(v)dv $$

Now I'm thinking about using taylor's expansion for f because when $ h $ approaches 0:

$$f'(hv+x) = f^{(2)}hv +\cfrac{(hv)^2}{2} f^{3}(x)+\cfrac{(hv)^3}{3!}f^{4}(x)+ o(h^3)$$
but seeing this calculation, I don't know whether it will get me to prove that the order is indeed $O(h^2)$ and $O(h)$.

**How should I proceed?**

Comment: 1, Why do you refer to the order as being both $O(h^2)$ *and* $O(h)$? 2. $O(h^2)$ is not the same as $o(h^2)$.

Comment: @jbowman thanks for your reply. 1/ In the proposition I came across both $O(h^2)$ and $O(h)$ which is part of my confusion. 2/ I know that $O(h^2)$ and $o(h^2)$ aren't the same but $o(h)$ implies $O(h)$ so I thought taylor expansion was a good start.

Comment: You have to use the Taylor series expansion and the calculations are not very good looking (especially near the boundary.) Just after a quick googling, I found this link: http://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/17Sp_403/Lec7-density.pdf

Do you want me to give this as an answer?

Comment: @SubrataPal which part of the calculation I did is wrong? Is taking $f'$ inside of the integral is wrong? I'd appreciate your answer yes

Comment: @wageeh No. Sorry, I misread the question the first time; I am attaching my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, I'm following this question: [Expectation of derivative of kernel density estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/394560/327787).

With some abuse in notation, we can write, for any fixed $x,$
\begin{align}
h E(\hat{f}'(x)) &= \frac{1}{h} \mathbb E\left[K'\left(\frac{X-x}{h} \right)  \right]\\
&=\int f(t) \cdot \frac{1}{h} K'\left(\frac{t-x}{h} \right) dt \\
&=\Bigg[f(t) \cdot K\left(\frac{t-x}{h}\right)\Bigg]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int K\left(\frac{t-x}{h} \right) \cdot f'(t)dt \\ 
&= -\int K\left(\frac{t-x}{h} \right) \cdot f'(t)dt
\end{align}
using integration by parts, and both $f$ and $K$ are valid pdf.

Now, take $u=(t-x)/h$ and $du=dt/h,$ gives
\begin{align}
E(\hat{f}'(x)) - f'(x) &= \frac{-1}{h}\int K\left(\frac{t-x}{h} \right) \cdot f'(t)dt - f'(x)\\  
&= -\int K(u) \cdot \left[f'(x+uh)-f'(x)\right] du \\ 
&= -\int K(u) \cdot \left[f''(x)(uh)+f'''(x)(uh)^2/2  + o(h^2)\right] du 
\end{align}
which you can check is $O(h)$.

I think derivative in both $K$ and $f$ is not possible in your approach.